# AutoComplete Doesn't Suggest Capital Letter Input PHP and XML

Tags: php, autocomplete

I'm creating a simple form and in this form I want to have an autocomplete functionality. http://www.script-tutorials.com/autocomplete-with-php-jquery-mysql-and-xml/ I read this tutorial, and for my data I created an XML file with the following format,

```
<inputs>
    <input>AA</input>
    <input>BAC</input>
    <input>AWT</input>
    <input>tag</input>
    <input>AHY</input>
</inputs>
```

And the method which handles the autocomplete is

```
 $aValues = $aIndexes = array();
        $sFileData = file_get_contents('data2.xml'); // reading file content
        $oXmlParser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
        xml_parse_into_struct($oXmlParser, $sFileData, $aValues, $aIndexes);
        xml_parser_free( $oXmlParser );

        $aTagIndexes = $aIndexes['ITEM'];
        if (count($aTagIndexes) <= 0) exit;
        foreach($aTagIndexes as $iTagIndex) {
            $sValue = $aValues[$iTagIndex]['value'];
            if (strpos($sValue, $sParam) !== false) {
                echo $sValue . "\n";
            }
        }
    break;
```

But the problem is, when I'm typing into the field, it always suggest the data which is lowercase. For example if I type either 'A' or 'a' it only suggest the data 'tag'

What is the problem, how should I solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strpos()` function is case sensitive, so it will only return "tag" as containing the letter "a". You should use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) if you want a case-insensitive check.